# Grid View within RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view which contains items as a gridview and text view.So basically am having an adapter for recycler view inside which I am  having an adapter for grid view. When I am trying to delete item from recycler view, gridview items are getting changed.. Should I notify grid view also the change? If yes ,how?

Please help me..Thanks in advance

Comment: Some one plz help me in this

Comment: can you post your code for this adapter ? I'm stuck in a similar situation. Thanks

Comment: noteslist.remove(notes);
                    rvnotes.getRecycledViewPool().clear();
                    notesadapter.notifyItemRemoved(selectedposition);

Answer (score 0):

No you should just notify the adapter for the removal of the item.

use this line when you're removing the item, in the adapter's scope:

```
notifyItemRemoved(int index);
```

Comment: Ya.. I did this already.. And the item is getting removed.But what happens is grid view containing images are getting interchanged between items..

Comment: Finally this saved me                    RecyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().clear();
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();